# R script by the method of the main factors in Rapid Miner

Tags: r, rapidminer

i try to find the solution - Specify the values of the factors (any of the 3) obtained from the group of variables Q79 for the fifth respondent, provided that the factors were obtained in the R script by the method of the main factors, the rotation procedure (varimax) was performed, the procedure for calculating factor points is regression, the number of factors is 3.

the data is in Excel file and inside it looks so -  for example the table

| q79_1 | q79_2 | q79_3 | q79_4 | q79_5 | q79_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 3 |

i want to see the result in RapidMiner

i write smth like this - but it doesn't work correctly

```
rm_main = function(data)
{
  library(psych)
  library(readxl)


  data <- read_excel("C:/Users/L2.xls")

  data1 <- data[, 1:38]

  fa <- fa(data1, nfactors = 3, rotate = "varimax", scores = "regression")
  factor_scores <- predict(fa, data1)
  loadings <- fa$loadings
  factors <- factor_scores[5,]
  result <- loadings %*% factors
  print(result)
}
```

Comment: In what way does “it not work correctly”? Please help yourself by helping us to help you by providing a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: mistake in class(result[[index]]) == "data.frame" || class(result[[index]]) ==  :

Apr 24, 2023 1:48:18 AM INFO:   'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Apr 24, 2023 1:48:18 AM INFO: main -> serializeResults

Comment: It is impossible to provide help without the data. In general, the rm_main function must return an object of type data frame. So adding a line like this before the last `}` may help. `return(data.frame(result))`